# Gulp-clean or del does partially delete the files

Tags: gulp

I have wanted to delete two folders inside the folder 'dest' so I did

```
gulp.task('del', function () {
  // add task
  return gulp.src('./app/static/dest', {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());

});
```

Under dest folder, there are js and css folder and inside them there are js and css files respectively. When I run gulp, it deletes js folder and files successfully but does not delete the css files. What is the problem?

By the way the default task function is:

```
gulp.task('default', ['del'], function() {
  gulp.start('transform');
  gulp.start('styles');
  gulp.watch('./app/static/src/js/*.js', ['transform'])
  gulp.watch('./app/static/src/css/*.scss', ['styles'])
});
```

Comment: Are you using gulp-clean plugin ? I reproduced your environment and its working correctly for me. Maybe permission issues ? Im assuming you have /app/static/dest/js & /app/static/dest/css; even with nested folders and files...

Comment: permission issues probably...;; I might have to check the differences... and yes you are correct. Hmm I just checked and still there is no problem with the permission.;;